# Customize tokenization using regex

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, tokenize

I have the following text:

```
4/21/2021 11:43:32 PM 0ED4 PACKET [OUTPUT] GET
```

The format of the log line may change and more fields may add into it but they are all single words. I only want to join date and time

I want to tokenize it to :

```
['4/21/2021 11:43:32 PM','0RU4', 'PACKET', 'OUTPUT', 'GET']
```

I have used this regex "`\\[|\\]|\,|\\s+|\W:|=`" which gives me the output as:

```
['4/21/2021', '11:43:32', 'PM', '0ED4', 'PACKET', 'OUTPUT', 'GET']
```

What changes should I make to the regex such that I get my desired output with the entire date and time as one token.

Comment: Can the log lines be longer/shorter? Or is the format always the same as you have shown?

Comment: They may change.

Comment: Then please explain the format in the question.

Comment: The format is same, only a few more fields can be added which are all one words

Comment: Try `(?:\W:|[][,=]|\s(?<!\d\d\s(?=(?:\d{1,2}(?::[0-5]\d){2}\s+)?[AP]M)))+`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e1zamB/1).

Comment: This only gives me blank spaces and square brackets

Comment: Then you need to show your code. I thought you were using `re.split`

Comment: I am using a spark pipeline and there i want to set a pattern ".token  = RegexTokenizer()\
        .setInputCols(['sentence'])\
        .setPattern("(?:\W:|[][,=]|\s(?<!\d\d\s(?=(?:\d{1,2}(?::[0-5]\d){2}\s+)?[AP]M)))+")\
        .setOutputCol('token')"

Comment: With my pattern, I think you need to use [`getGaps()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer.html#pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer.getGaps).

Comment: Im getting this error when I replace setPattern with getGaps "RegexTokenizer' object has no attribute 'getGaps'"

Comment: Hm, try `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M|[^]\s[]+` if you need a pattern that will match the tokens. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e1zamB/2).

Comment: The regex is working in python but not on spark

Comment: Right, it is Java flavor there. Then you need `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M|[^\s\[\]]+`

Comment: This is not possible. `/` is not a special regex character. See https://regex101.com/r/e1zamB/3. You should not use regex testers blindly. Always check them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a single regex pattern along with `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "4/21/2021 11:43:32 PM 0ED4 PACKET [OUTPUT] GET"
matches = re.findall(r'^(\S+ \S+ [AP]M) (\S+) (\S+) \[(\S+)\] (\w+)', inp)
print(matches)  # [('4/21/2021 11:43:32 PM', '0ED4', 'PACKET', 'OUTPUT', 'GET')]
```

Comment: maybe for compact `r'([^\s]+)'`: get everything between 2 white spaces

Comment: This wont be helpful if I give more sentences as input which contain more fields and are different for different lines

Comment: Please address Wiktor's comments under your question then.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following python ttp module. See the example:

```
from ttp import ttp
import json
import re

data_to_parse = "4/21/2021 11:43:32 PM 0ED4 PACKET [OUTPUT] GET"

ttp_template = """
{{ TIME | PHRASE }} PM {{REST | PHRASE}}
"""

parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
parser.parse()

# print result in JSON format
results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
#print(results)

#converting str to json. 
result = json.loads(results)

rest_split = result[0]['REST'].split()

desired_data = []
desired_data.append(f"{result[0]['TIME']} PM")

pattern = "\[(\S+)\]" # Just to capture everything between [], your OUTPUT data. 

for i in rest_split:
    if re.match(pattern, i):
        i = re.findall(pattern, i)
        desired_data.append(i[0])
        continue
    desired_data.append(i)

print(desired_data)
```

See the output of result first:

[image]

See the output of desired data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with regex?

```
s = '4/21/2021 11:43:32 PM 0ED4 PACKET [OUTPUT] GET'
s = s.replace(' [',' ').replace('] ',' ') #the output shows no square brackets

tags = [' AP ', ' PM ']
for t in tags:
    if t in s:
        start, end = s.split(t)
        start = (start + t).strip()
        result = [start, *end.split()]
        break
        
print(result)
#['4/21/2021 11:43:32 PM', '0ED4', 'PACKET', 'OUTPUT', 'GET']
```